# Active Record Query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to find all blog posts that have more than one comment associated to it. How do I do this using an ActiveRecord query in the rails console?

blog_post 
  has_many :comments

```
 blog = Blog.all
 blog.find(:comments > 1)
```

Comment: You have to try something first and post what you tried.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a bit vaguely defined but I still try to answer it.

The easiest way is probably a counter cache for your comments in your `BlogPost` model. This solution also scales better if you have a lot of comments in one blog post.

For example:

```
class BlogPost < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :blog_post, dependent: :destroy, counter_cache: true
end
```

Then just add a migration which adds a `comments_count` to the blog posts table and Rails takes care of everything else.

```
class AddCommentsCountToBlogPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :blog_posts, :comments_count, :integer
  end
end
```

Now you can do things like this:

```
posts_with_comments = BlogPost.where('comments_count >= ?', 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
blog_ids_with_comments = Blog.select(:id).
  joins(:comments).
  groupBy('blogs.id').
  having('count(comments.id) > 1')

blogs = Blog.find blog_ids_with_comments
```

You have to turn this SQL into an ActiveRecord query:

```
select blogs.id from blogs join comments on blog.id = blog_id
  group by blogs.id having count(comments.id) > 1;
```

You can actually reduce it to one line if you select all the `Blog` fields and group by all the `Blog` fields. Rails might have a shortcut to specify all fields of a record.